# what if set x.domain.com and y.domain.com to the same ip address in DNS?

Tags: nginx

if I set x.domain.com and y.domain.com to the same ip address, Does it mean Nginx couldn't tell the differences between x.domain.com and y.domain.com?

Is it impossible to map x.domain.com and y.domain in the server directive in the server context to the different folder?

I also want to learn more about how the computer network work? Anyone could give me some resources?

Comment: That really looks like two different questions. I can't help with the exact config, but for the first two parts, virtualhosts or its equivalent would do the trick

Comment: It's actually three different questions.  The last is "I want to learn about networking.  What should I read?" and would be far better off as a proper standalone question (although I have my doubts that it would survive, even though a Community Wiki bibliography would surely be a help to people).

Answer (score 5):

> if I set x.domain.com and y.domain.com to the same ip address, Does it mean Nginx couldn't tell the differences between x.domain.com and y.domain.com?
>
> Is it impossible to map x.domain.com and y.domain in the server directive in the server context to the different folder?

It can; all HTTP clients send a `Host` header along with the request. For example,

```
GET /page.html HTTP/1.1
Host: x.domain.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0
```

This is very widely used; see [virtual hosting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_hosting). For nginx configuration, see [VirtualHostExample on nginx wiki](http://wiki.nginx.org/VirtualHostExample).

Answer (score 2):

Multiple (sub-)domains like x.domain.com and y.domain.com on the same ip adress are nothing special.

It's called "named based virtual hosting", and you can find more informations on wikipedia or in the nginx documentation:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_hosts#Name-based
- http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html